# Passing values to component using history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I try to navigate from one component to another page using routes and need to pass some parameters across with it. I have tried providing them as state using history.push(..) as seen below but it doesn't work, both state and props are empty.

In the holder component, Holder.js

At top:

```
import history from '../routes/history';
```

In render function

```
<Button variant="contained" onClick={() => { history.push('/share', {
            account: this.props.account, credential: JSON.stringify(this.state.credentialInfo)});
            window.location.reload();}} fullWidth  sx={{mt: 3, mb: 2}}>Share ID</Button>
```

In index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route path="/share" element={<SharePage  />} />
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In history.js

```
 import { createBrowserHistory as history} from 'history';

 export default history();
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include a more complete code example? It looks like you are using a `history` object *outside* the router. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Additionally, using `window.location.reload();` will reload your entire app, losing any state. What are you reloading for?

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question please let me know if there is any more code I can provide. The reason I was calling this is because after the button is clicked, the link changes to .../share however the share page itself does not load.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using `react-router-dom` version 6. In RRDv6 imperative navigation is accomplished via a `navigate` function returned from the [useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate) hook. The issue is that the RRDv6 `BrowserRouter` component instantiates and maintains its own internal `history` object and state. You can create your own, but since it's a separate history context it won't work with your router, routing, and navigation.

[useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)

> ```
> declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;
>
> interface NavigateFunction {
>   (
>     to: To,
>     options?: { replace?: boolean; state?: any }
>   ): void;
>   (delta: number): void;
> }
> ```

Import the `useNavigate` hook and access the `navigate` function, sending along state with the route transition. Route state is part of the options object as the second parameter to the `navigate` function.

This is only validly used in function components though, and the component using the button appears to be a class component. You can either convert the class component to a function component ***or*** create your own custom `withNavigation` Higher Order Component so the `navigate` function can be injected as props.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const withNavigation = Component => props => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return <Component {...props} navigate={navigate} />;
};

export default withNavigation;
```

Import the new HOC and decorate your class component, accessing the `navigate` function from props.

```
import withNavigation from '../withNavigation';

...

<Button
  variant="contained"
  onClick={() => {
    this.props.navigate(
      '/share',
      {
        state: {
          account: this.props.account,
          credential: JSON.stringify(this.state.credentialInfo),
        }
      },
    );
  }}
  fullWidth
  sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}
>
  Share ID
</Button>

...

export default withNavigation(MyClassComponent);
```

Route state is accessed the same way in v6 as it was in v5, save for the `location` object being a prop. Use the [useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation) hook to access the `location` object and its `state` property.

[useLocation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation)

```
const { state } = useLocation();

...

const { account, credential } = state || {};
```

If `SharePage` is another class component then you can expand your `withNavigation` HOC to include other RRD hooks and inject other props.

Answer (score 0):

No. you can only:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


function YourComponent() {
   const history = useHistory();

   const share = useCallback(() => {
    history.push(`/share?account=${this.props.account}&credential=${JSON.stringify(this.state.credentialInfo)}`);
   }, []);

   return (
      <Button variant="contained" onClick={share}>Share ID</Button>
    )
}
`
```

Comment: Is this literally the only way to do this? I cannot put these details in the link. Is there another design I can use?